# Jquery mobile 1.4 header footer lose css styling during page transition

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I just switched to JQuery Mobile 1.4, now when I do page transition, both header and footer lose css styling for a while before applying again.

IOS 7.04

Main index file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/library/phonegap/cordova_ios.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/library/JQuery/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.css">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/application/base.css">
    <script data-main="js/main.js" src="js/library/require/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="main_body">
</body>
</html>
```

some pages that transit between each other with header and footer

page1

```
<div id="login_template_wrapper">
    <div id="leftmainmenu" class="menu-container" data-position="left" data-display="overlay">
    </div>
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-id="iheader" data-tap-toggle="false" data-hide-during-focus="false">
        <h1><%print(T('LOGIN'));%></h1>
        <!-- <a id="menu_link" data-role="button" data-icon="gear" data-position="left"><%print(T('LEFTMAINMENU'))%></a> -->
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content" class="main-content">
        <div id="login-content_wrapper" class="content_wrapper">
            <div class="content_inner">
                <div id="login_input">
                    <div data-role="label"><%print(T('USERNAME'));%></div><input bc-data-role="input" class="login-form" name="username" value="<%print(logindata['du'])%>"/>
                    <div data-role="label"><%print(T('PASSWORD'));%></div><input bc-data-role="input" class="login-form" type="password" name="password" value="<%print(logindata['dp'])%>"/>
                    <input type="submit" class="login-form" data-role="button" id="login_submit" value="<%print(T('LOGIN'));%>"/>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" id="rememberme" <%if (logindata['rm']) {print('checked');}%> />
                                <label for="rememberme"><%print(T('REMEMBER_ME'))%></label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="rememberpass" id="rememberpass" <%if (logindata['rp']) {print('checked');}%> />
                                <label for="rememberpass"><%print(T('REMEMBER_PASSWD'))%></label>
                            </fieldset>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /content inner -->
        </div><!-- /content wrapper-->
    </div><!-- /content -->
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="ifooter" data-tap-toggle="false" data-hide-during-focus="false">
        <div id="login_links" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <a data-role="button" data-icon="edit" href="#registration"><%print(T('REGISTRATION'))%></a>
            <a data-role="button" data-icon="refresh" href="#passwordretrieval"><%print(T('RETRIEVEPASSWORD'))%></a>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div>
```

page2

```
<div id="registration_template_wrapper">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-id="iheader"  data-tap-toggle="false" data-hide-during-focus="false">
        <h1><%print(T('REGISTRATION'));%></h1>
        <a href="#login/reverse" data-role="button" data-icon="back" data-position="left"><%print(T('BACK'))%></a>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content" class="main-content">
        <div id="login-content_wrapper" class="content_wrapper">
            <div class="content_inner">
                <ul id="registration_input" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                    <li><div data-role="label"><%print(T('USERNAME1'));%></div><input bc-data-role="input" class="registration-form" id="USERNAME1" name="USERNAME1" value="" data-mini="true"/></li>
                    <li><div data-role="label"><%print(T('USERNAME2'));%></div><input bc-data-role="input" class="registration-form" id="USERNAME2" name="USERNAME2" value="" data-mini="true"/></li>
                    <li><div data-role="label"><%print(T('PASSWORD1'));%></div><input bc-data-role="input" class="registration-form" type="password" id="PASSWORD1" name="PASSWORD1" value="" data-mini="true"/></li>
                    <li><div data-role="label"><%print(T('PASSWORD2'));%></div><input bc-data-role="input" class="registration-form" type="password" id="PASSWORD2" name="PASSWORD2" value="" data-mini="true"/></li>
                    <!-- 
                    <li><div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="showpass" id="showpass"/>
                            <label for="showpass"><%print(T('SHOWPASS'))%></label>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div></li>
                    <li><button id="registration_clean"><%print(T('CLEAN'))%></button></li> -->
                    <li><button id="registration_save"><%print(T('REGISTRATION'))%></li></button>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /content inner -->
        </div><!-- /content wrapper-->
    </div><!-- /content -->
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="ifooter"  data-tap-toggle="false" data-hide-during-focus="false">
        <div id="login_links" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <a data-role="button" data-icon="edit" href="#registration"><%print(T('REGISTRATION'))%></a>
            <a data-role="button" data-icon="refresh" href="#passwordretrieval"><%print(T('RETRIEVEPASSWORD'))%></a>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div>
```

I load page template through backbone view, and do the page transition use the following code

```
$.mobile.changePage(__this.currentView.$el, {'reverse': reverse, 'changeHash': false, 'transition': mobile_transition});
```

Everything worked fine in 1.4 alpha and beta, but in 1.4 release, the header and footer loses css styling for a while before applying css style again.

Comment: Everything worked fine in 1.4 alpha and beta,

Comment: even though, without code, nobody would be able to assist. Also, are you using custom theme made with ThemeRoller?

Comment: I added code to the question

Comment: try this `$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", __this.currentView.$el, {'reverse': reverse, 'changeHash': false, 'transition': mobile_transition});`

Comment: It does not work, still flashing

Comment: It seems it is the theme file that causes this flashing behaviour

Comment: I've experienced exactly the same. It appears that the problem only occurs when using data-id. I solved it using the below suggestion and adding data-theme. But still it does seem like it's a defect in JQM1.4 (1.4.5 in my case)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem. My solution was to directly add `data-theme="a"` to the header.

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-id="iheader"  data-tap-toggle="false" data-hide-during-focus="false" data-theme="a">
    <h1><%print(T('REGISTRATION'));%></h1>
    <a href="#login/reverse" data-role="button" data-icon="back" data-position="left"><%print(T('BACK'))%></a>
</div><!-- /header -->
```

I believe this is something to do with the new theme inheriting mechanism but i cant seem to find any useful documentation on the subject.

Comment: Thanks, it works, unfortunate theme doest work well in jquerymobile 1.4

Comment: Yes @ Max thank you this is truley very great things, verry great it help me many time over @ Max! ha ha i just can not stop it now.. ha ha

Comment: Thank you Sir! I owe you something :)

Answer (score -1):

I tried the Max's answer but it didn't work for me.

The "fixed" header/footer are moved outside the containing "page" div during transition and moved back in after the animation. You should add additional css selectors to apply the styling on the moved header/footer.

For example if you current selector is `.ui-page-theme-a .ui-bar-a .ui-btn.back-link` , add another selector for your css like `.ui-mobile-viewport .ui-bar-a .ui-btn.back-link`. This is because the header/footer is no longer inside `.ui-page-theme-a` and is inside `.ui-mobile-viewport` during the transition.

Hope it helps!